# Разные onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, activity, activity-life-cycle

Сегодня заметил что в `AppCompatActivity` используется `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle b)` с модификатором `protected`.

А в `Activity` используется `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle b, PersistableBundle pb)` и модификатор у него `public`

в чем причина наличия двух `onSaveInstanceState` ? Какой из них использовать правильней ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это связано с тем, что обычно довольно сложно сериализовать `Bundle`, конечно можно, но это довольно утомительное занятие.

`PersistableBundle` можно достаточно просто сериализовать (на диск/БД) и потом восстановиться оттуда.

Делается это так:

1. Сначала пишем `PersistableBundle` в `Parcel` - через `writeToParcel()`
2. Полученный `Parcel` легко сериализуется через `Parcel.marshall()`, который возвращает массив `byte[]`, далее уже можно этот массив записать куда угодно, например при должном старании даже в `SharedPreferences`

**Update**
Забыл упомянуть, что `PersistableBundle` в отличие от `Bundle` содержит только простые объекты, которые можно без ущерба сериализовать и десериализовать. В то время, как `Bundle` может содержать достаточно сложные объекты, которые невозможно или очень трудно сериализовать, поэтому бездумная сериализация `Bundle` через `Parcel.marshall()` может привести к проблемам.

Comment: но ведь `Bundle` тоже можно записать в `Parcel`, ведь он реализует `Parcelable`, и провернуть те же действия, в чем же преимущество, или я что - то путаю ?

Comment: смотрите апдейт ответа

Comment: спасибо за детали

Answer (score 2):

В 95% случаев правильно использовать вариант с один аргументом, обычным `Bundle`

Второй метод, как пишут в [доке](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle,%20android.os.PersistableBundle))

> This is the same as onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) but is called for activities created with the attribute persistableMode set to persistAcrossReboots.

Т.е. часть методов жизненного цикла имеют методы с дополнительным аргументом, в котором хранятся данные сохранённые при ребуте девайса. Чтобы эти методы вызвались активити должна быть вами явно создана для этого.